# ¿Alguien sabe como llenar desde un controlador un Pie Graphics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, google-visualization

He estado buscando en internet una manera de llenar los datos desde un controlador, el código esta programado en ASP.NET MVC 5 RAZOR.

Les muestro a continuación el código:

VIEW

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable();

        var options = {
            title: 'Inventario físico'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

En la parte que dice var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(); dentro de los paréntesis es ahí donde meteré la consulta del controlador para llenar mi gráfico de pastel.

A continuación les muestro el método del CONTROLADOR.

```
//OBTENEMOS DATOS DESDE LA BD PARA GENERAR LA GRAFICA DE PASTEL
        public string estadisticasGrafico()
        {
            DataTable datos = new DataTable();
            datos = FunctionInventario279.estadisticasGrafico();

            string strDatos = "[['Conteos pendientes', 'Cantidad'],";

            foreach (DataRow dr in datos.Rows)
            {
                strDatos = strDatos + "[";
                strDatos = strDatos + "'" + dr[4] + "'" + "," + dr[5];
                strDatos = strDatos + "],";
            }

            strDatos = strDatos + "]";

            return strDatos;

        }
```

Ya teniendo los datos consultados desde la base ya se podrá mostrar el gráfico de pastel.

Los datos se mandan a llamar desde un SP, mediante una cadena de conexión (método) en el cual devuelve un datatable.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Creo que esta [página](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Charts-in-ASPNet-MVC-Google-Pie-Doughnut-Chart-example-with-database-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) te puede ayudar. Si esta es la solución, por favor, no olvides [publicar y aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Saludos.

Comment: Francisco  ¿esto es una pregunta? o ¿estas exponiendo como realizar una solución? si es una respuesta debes agregarla como comenta Mauricio.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que el método `estadisticasGrafico()` retorne lo siguiente:

```
[
    [
        "Conteos pendientes",
        "Cantidad"
    ],
    [
        "Item1",
        11
    ],
    [
        "Item2",
        2
    ],
    [
        "Item3",
        2
    ]
]
```

Las *comillas dobles* hacen que funcione correctamente, en esta demostración.

Debe hacer una solicitud Http `XMLHttpRequest()` (AJAX), para obtener los datos y presentarlos en pantalla.

Para ello, he preparado una función Helper para solicitudes `XMLHttpRequest()`, con lo necesario para su caso.

```
var newXHR;

function sendXHR(options, callback) {
  newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  newXHR.open("GET", options.url, true);
  newXHR.send(null);
  newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
      callback(this.response);
    }
  };
}
```

Utilización:

```
sendXHR({url: "http://miurl"}, function(datosRetornados)
{
   // Código con los datosRetornados.
});
```

Debido que no tengo modo de probar su método de su controlador, tengo la siguiente URL para probar.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/79f1d96defc939cd22c1cf60296c2bda/raw/1c8d792fb61f6186f1e329a34f214b66bfabb2d4/estadisticasGrafico.json

Asegúrese de reemplazarlo por la url correcta.

**Demostración:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var newXHR;

    function sendXHR(options, callback) {
      newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      newXHR.open("GET", options.url, true);
      newXHR.send(null);
      newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
          callback(this.response);
        }
      };
    }


    // Ejemplo de ejecución.
    sendXHR({
      url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/79f1d96defc939cd22c1cf60296c2bda/raw/1c8d792fb61f6186f1e329a34f214b66bfabb2d4/estadisticasGrafico.json"
    }, function(response) {
      var datosControlador = JSON.parse(response);

      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(datosControlador);

        var options = {
          title: 'Inventario físico'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```